# Trouble completing a Java ArrayList sorting program that asks user how to sort ArrayList

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, input

My code is within a package and divided into two separate .java file files. It prints a list of options for how the ArrayList can be sorted, which the user can select by entering the right number. However, for some reason it does not print any sorted list after I input, well anything. Can anyone help?

Here is my custom Object class, Contact.java:

```
package Sorter;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class Contact {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String state;
    private Integer age;

public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String state, Integer age) {

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.state = state;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public static Comparator<Contact> lastNameComparator = new Comparator<Contact>() {

    public int compare(Contact s1, Contact s2) {
        String contactLastName1 = s1.getLastName().toUpperCase();
        String contactLastName2 = s2.getLastName().toUpperCase();

        return contactLastName1.compareTo(contactLastName2);
    }
};

public static Comparator<Contact> stateComparator = new Comparator<Contact>() {

    public int compare(Contact s1, Contact s2) {
        String state1 = s1.getState().toUpperCase();
        String state2 = s2.getState().toUpperCase();

        return state1.compareTo(state2);
    }
};

public static Comparator<Contact> ageComparator = new Comparator<Contact>() {

    public int compare(Contact s1, Contact s2) {
        int age1 = s1.getAge();
        int age2 = s2.getAge();

        return age1 - age2;
    }
};

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ("First Name: " + firstName + ", Last Name: " + lastName + ", State: " + state + ", Age: " + age);
}
}
```

And here is my Sort.java:
    package Sorter;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestSortOptions {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = initializeContactsArray();
    promptForOption(contacts);
}

private static ArrayList<Contact> initializeContactsArray() {
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    contacts.add(new Contact("Joe", "Jones", "IL", 35));
    contacts.add(new Contact("Bill", "Barnes", "OH", 62));
    contacts.add(new Contact("Ida", "Know", "FL", 23));
    contacts.add(new Contact("Adam", "Ant", "MI", 14));
    contacts.add(new Contact("Jane", "Doe", "CA", 41));

    return contacts;
}

private static void promptForOption(ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Options \nSort by Last Name:  [1] " + "\nSort by Home State: [2] "
            + "\nSort by Age:        [3] " + "\nExit Application:   [0] " + "\n\nPlease enter your choice: ");
    String answer = input.next();

    if (answer == "1") {
        Collections.sort(contacts, Contact.lastNameComparator);
        for (Contact contact : contacts) {
            System.out.println(contact);
        }

        if (answer == "2") {
            Collections.sort(contacts, Contact.stateComparator);
            for (Contact contact : contacts) {
                System.out.println(contact);
            }

            if (answer == "3") {
                Collections.sort(contacts, Contact.ageComparator);
                for (Contact contact : contacts) {
                    System.out.println(contact);
                }

                if (answer == "0") {
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: `if (answer == "1") {` - Remember that you can't use `==` on Strings.  You need to use `.equals()`.

Comment: @DM thanks for pointing that out; I made a rookie mistake in thinking it was the opposite. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to print contact list after every option. It would be better to call it once. Replace definition of your promptForOption API with the code given below

```
private static void promptForOption(ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Options \nSort by Last Name:  [1] " + "\nSort by Home State: [2] "
        + "\nSort by Age:        [3] " + "\nExit Application:   [0] " + "\n\nPlease enter your choice: ");
String answer = input.next();

    switch(answer)
    {
    case "1":Collections.sort(contacts, Contact.lastNameComparator);
             break;
    case "2":Collections.sort(contacts, Contact.stateComparator);
             break;
    case "3":Collections.sort(contacts, Contact.ageComparator);
             break;
    case "4":Collections.sort(contacts, Contact.ageComparator);
             break;
    case "0":
    default: System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
             System.exit(0);
    }
    for (Contact contact : contacts) {
        System.out.println(contact);
    }
}
```

You need to also update constructor definition to capture age.

```
public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String state, Integer age) {

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.state = state;
    this.age=age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you are nesting the if statements when you really shouldn't be. It should be in the format:

```
    if (answer.equals("1")) {
        //Do business
    } else if (answer.equals("2") {
        //Do other business
    } else if (answer.equals("3") {
        //Do other other business
    } else {
        //Bad input
    }
```

A switch case can also be used if you would like:

```
    switch(input.next) {
        case "1":
            //Do business
            break;
        case "2":
            //Do other business
            break;
        case "3":
            //Do other other business
            break;
        default: 
            //Bad input
            break;
    }
```

Keep in mind the flow of your method now:
If the user inputs "1", then sort in the lastName method and then print in the for-loop. You are then checking if the answer is "2", which it obviously is not because you are still within the "if it is '1'" block (and you aren't taking in any additional input). Remember that when you open an if-block, anything you put inside it will be executed if the condition is true. If you look at your code and reason through the flow, you will see what is flawed about your control statements. To exit with System.exit(0) in your last conditional statement, the answer would have to be 1, 2, 3 *and* 0.

Also, see [Leozeo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42355561/4959124) for the business logic code and refactoring to remove code duplication in each control statement.

Comment: Thank you! As for the nested ifs, that was the Format function (Shift + Ctrl + F) in Eclipse doing that.

Thank you for pointing out the flaw with System.exit(0). I was trying to find some sort of way to exit a program and that kept coming up as a suggestion. Since I'm newer to Java, I didn't really know any better, so this is extremely helpful to point out!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @IwataFan I figured that is what you were confused about because that is something that can be confusing to newer programmers. Control statements can be very helpful but they can also be sort of confusing until you reason through them one by one. If you think I answered your question, please accept my answer as it may help others in the future!